# How do they get these two expressions (dθ/dx) and (dθ/dy)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

I tried deriving the tanθ with respective to x and y but couldn't arrive at the correct solutions. Could anyone please show or give a hint? Thank you

Comment: Solve for $\theta$ first and take the derivative of the arctan.

Comment: I guess you used $\tan'=1+\tan^2.$ Here, a more practical (but obviously equivalent) expression is $\tan'=\frac1{\cos^2}.$

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating the second equation with respect to $x$ and $y$ gives
$$-\frac y{x^2}=\frac1{\cos^2\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x},\quad\frac 1x=\frac1{\cos^2\theta}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}.$$
To conclude, use that $x^2=r^2\cos^2\theta.$

Comment: Perfect! Got it :D I only did it half way apparently